# angular 6 scss background image not being read

Tags: angular, image, background-image, assets

In my angular 6 app I have the following in my scss file:

```
.pictureplaceholder{
  background-image: url("assets/images/profilepictureplaceholder/PersonPlaceholder.png");
}
```

that is the correct path to the resource.  yet I get this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/venueadmin/parentadminview/venueuserprofile/venueuserprofile.component.scss
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/fixedsuitsandtables/src/app/venueadmin/parentadminview/venueuserprofile/venueuserprofile.component.scss:11:20: Can't resolve 'assets/images/profilepictureplaceholder/PersonPlaceholder.png' in '/home/rickus/Documents/softwareProjects/211hospitality/suitsandtables/frontend/fixedsuitsandtables/src/app/venueadmin/parentadminview/venueuserprofile'

   9 | 
  10 | .pictureplaceholder{
> 11 |   background-image: url('assets/images/profilepictureplaceholder/PersonPlaceholder.png');
     |                    ^
  12 | }
  13 |
```

My other images that are in the assets folder are working. Very strange. Anyone know what this is?

Comment: did u try removing the double quotes and make sure the path provided is relative path too `background-image: url(assets/images/profilepictureplaceholder/PersonPlaceholder.png);`

Comment: yes, and attempted the relative path, none are working. its really werid.

Comment: Add / in front of assests and try

Comment: @KeshanNageswaran got it posted the answer. Thank you for the help

Comment: no worried cheers

Comment: What about using `url(/assets/image......)`, I.e. with leading slash?

Answer (score 22):

Add a / to the beginning of each URL.

```
background-image: url("/../assets/images/profilepictureplaceholder/PersonPlaceholder.png");
```

based on your directory hierarchy adjust your relative path. But add a forward slash at the beginning.

For more info [refer](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4778#issuecomment-280638820)

Answer (score 5):

got it. It was a relative path without the ""

so

```
background-image: url(../../../../assets/images/profilepictureplaceholder/PersonPlaceholder.png);
```

Comment: really? what is the syntax of   `./` whats it purpose?

Comment: `./` is angular-cli's alias to `src`

Answer (score 2):

We can use relative path instead of absolute path:

```
$assetPath: '~src/assets/images/';
$logo-img: '#{$assetPath}logo.png';
@mixin logo {
  background-image: url(#{$logo-img});
}

.logo {
    max-width: 65px;
    @include logo;
 }
```

Comment: Best solution. Tanx Aarji ;)

Answer (score 1):

use in this way

```
$asset-images-path : "assets/images/imagePathHere";
background-image: image-url("#{$asset-images-path}/imageNameWithExtension.png");
```

Comment: i added only url then it worked - background-image: url("#{$img-global}/sw-title-bg.png");  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

URL might not be right:

```css
url('/./assets/images/bike.jpg');
```

Comment: Please add some expaination

Comment: This code worked for me after migration form CSS to SCSS in Angular 10 project.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the above-mentioned methods but this worked for me

```
#imge6{
    background-image: url("../../../../assets/5.png");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

maybe solve someone else's problem.